# Node, Socket.io, and Redis - multiple instances

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm confused about running node with more than one dyno on Heroku and how to make socket.io/redis accessible across instances. I'm using socket.io 0.9.16.

(1) First, when I scale to two `dynos` in Heroku, this just means two node instances?

(2) Second, When I create an instance of `io` like so:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

then when a second `node` instance gets created then a second `io` instance gets created with it - is that correct?

(3) And the reason to use `redis` is to create a single store accessible by all instances - is that correct?

However, when I create a new `redisstore` for `io` like so:

```
var ioRedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis');
io.set('store', new ioRedisStore({
  redisPub    : redis.createClient(),
  redisSub    : redis.createClient(),
  redisClient : redis.createClient()
}));
```

(4) Isn't this `redis` instance now created by each node instance and then set as the store for each `io` instance? How does this cross instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) First, when I scale to two dynos in Heroku, this just means two node instances?

You can think of it that way, yes.

> (2) Second, When I create an instance of io like so: ...

Yes, that is correct.

> (3) And the reason to use redis is to create a single store accessible by all instances - is that correct?

Yes.

> (4) Isn't this redis instance now created by each node instance and then set as the store for each io instance? How does this cross instances?

[Redis](http://redis.io) is a key-value server. Calling redis.createClient() just creates a connection to a redis server, it doesn't actually create an instance of a redis server anywhere. You're going to need to have an instance of redis running somewhere ([Heroku has a few options](https://addons.heroku.com/?q=redis)). Then you are going to need to setup your code to explicitly connect to that one instance by passing the port and host to `redis.createClient` ([docs](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#rediscreateclientport-host-options)).

So, if you have a redis instance running on port 6379 (default) at 10.0.1.100 (picked randomly), you'd do:

```
var ioRedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis');
io.set('store', new ioRedisStore({
  redisPub    : redis.createClient(6379, '10.0.1.100'),
  redisSub    : redis.createClient(6379, '10.0.1.100'),
  redisClient : redis.createClient(6379, '10.0.1.100')
}));
```

That way all your node instances share the same redis instance and they can coordinate through it.

Comment: That explanation for (4) was exactly what I needed.